# Importing .sql file on windows to postgresql

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql, import

I have a .sql file that was created by postgresql a while back. I now want to import this file onto a windows machine running postgresql.

How do I do this. The file is about 1.5gb.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should use [psql](http://psql.sourceforge.net/) command line tool:

```
psql -h hostname -p port_number -U username -f your_file.sql databasename
```

Comment: what is I want to replace the existing table while loading like this? will it succeed?

Answer (score 26):

click on the SQL Shell and log into the database and use import

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]:
Password for user postgres:
psql (9.2.4)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \i c:/data/data01.sql
```

Comment: Note inverted "/" symbol, instead of "\" usually used in Windows.

Comment: this is giving me "C:: Permission denied" , i tried changing the disk as well.
didn't  get fixed even after running it as an administrator

Comment: confirm that you are using "/" and not "\" @jakub noted above. It is VERY important. And if you have spaces, enclose the path in quotation marks

Answer (score 20):

start you psql command tool, it will give you dialog like the following

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:yourport
Username [postgres]:
Password for user postgres:**********
```

then connect to your database

```
postgres=# \c yourdatabase;
```

then import the file

```
yourdatabase=# \i c:/path/path/data/data01.sql
```

note the / for directory separator & no spaces in file path

Answer (score 13):

This also works for me:

```
psql dbname username < file.sql
```

Comment: Just a note: the "<" operator won't work in Windows Powershell.

Comment: Good point. I've been using [`cmder`](https://cmder.net/) for so long I forgot the differences!

Answer (score 2):

[command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eepiz.png)

*open your [cmd window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eepiz.png) and type the following (make sure the path of postgres is correct)*

> ."C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres -d dbname <./query.sql

Answer (score 2):

```
psql -U <dbusername>
if the prompt makes you enter password, do that.
\c <yourdatabasename>
\i 'thepathusing/delimiter.sql'
```

Two points you need to watch out that

- Use `/` as writing path of the file instead of `\`.
- Use single quote
  symbol `'` instead of `"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it with a URI connection string make sure the arguments **are before the URI**, Powershell examples:

Works on windows:

```
.\psql -f TestFile.sql $connString

.\psql -c 'SELECT Version();' $connString
```

Won't work on windows (URI connection before arguments):

```
.\psql $connString -c 'SELECT Version();'
```