# how to execute .sql files in postgres database

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am using postgres database with PostGIS and PGAdmin. I have many .sql files with different sizes like 300MB, 280MB etc to be inserted into database. What is the best way to do it i.e through java code or some psql commands. I am very new to java and postgres database also. Please give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 56):

Use the `psql` command line tool:

```
psql -f file_with_sql.sql
```

This command executes all commands line-by-line (except when the file contains BEGIN…END blocks. In this case, commands in blocks execute in a transaction). To wrap all commands in a transaction use the `--single-transaction` switch:

```
psql --single-transaction -f file_with_sql.sql
```

For more options:

```
psql --help
```

Comment: Does this execute the entire sql file in one transaction or does it use a new transaction for each line in the file?

Answer (score 15):

Just put it on the command line after `psql`:

```
psql example.sql
```

`psql` will take the file and run each line to the server.

If the server is not running on your computer, you will need to specify the hostname to the computer and a username to log into the server with:

```
psql -h server.postgres.com -U username example.sql
```

To send multiple files, just list them all:

```
psql example1.sql example2.sql example3.sql
```

Comment: see [PSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html)

Comment: i have very big files and those need to be send to another server. so it is taking long time through psql. is there anyway to do directly from pgadmin?

Comment: Better look below link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204274/importing-sql-file-on-windows-to-postgresql

Answer (score 14):

Another approach is to use the psql command **\i**. For example,

Let say we have the file **run.sql** in the path `~/sql/run.sql`

```
$ cd ~/sql/

$ psql -h <host> -U <user> <database>
```

```
<database> => 

<database> => \i 'run.sql'
```

DONE

Answer (score 4):

If the .sql file itself creates the database, such as:

```
\echo 'Delete and recreate database?'
\prompt 'Return for yes or control-C to cancel > ' foo

DROP DATABASE my-db;
CREATE DATABASE my-db;
\connect my-db
```

The easiest way is to run the command:

```
psql < my-file.sql
```