# How to import several sql files into postgreSQL using batch script?

Tags: sql, postgresql, batch-file, import

I have a set of sql files

```
file1.sql
file2.sql
....
```

that contain table inserts `INSERT INTO <tablename> (...) VALUES (....);` in a directory. I would like to add a command into a existing batch file so that it iterates over each file. 
Currently I use the command

```
<postgreSQLCommandWithParameters> -U <user> -d <database> -f <pathToSQL>\complete.sql -q
```

I looked into a for loop but I missing the parameter to point to the correct directory.

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do <postgreSQL> -U <user>  -d <database>  -E -i"%%G"
```

**Therefore how can I use a for loop to iterate over all sql files which contain insert commands?** 
 As a side question: *And what is the syntax in the `for` loop in batch scripts?*

Comment: you did not mention shell

Comment: You could try to use Powershell. Check this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204274/importing-sql-file-on-windows-to-postgresql)

Comment: Also look here. Specific question on how to loop through files in powershell. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847145/loop-through-files-in-a-directory-using-powershell

Comment: I think this already has an answer. Check this out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537204/execute-several-sql-files-in-a-single-transaction-using-postgresql-and-bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537204/execute-several-sql-files-in-a-single-transaction-using-postgresql-and-bash)

Answer (score 0):

So I used the following command

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`dir <pathToSQLFiles> ^|  findstr .sql `) DO (

        <postgreSQL>  %1 -U <user> -d <database> -f  <pathToSQLFiles>\%%F -q

    )
```

And here are some cliffnotes

- `"tokens=4 USEBACKQ"` takes the numbered items to read from each line and also includes names with space in them
- `^|  findstr .sql` filters all SQL files